# matplotlib scatter plot erases an image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create a scatter plot, then plot it, save it to a file, load this file back and try to show the image. Why do I get an empty image?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Then I save the image:

```
plt.savefig("./image.png")
```

Load it back:

```
img = mpimg.imread("./image.png")
img.shape
(288, 432, 4)
```

And when I plot it I get an a blank image, why?

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.show()` erases the image.  You can call `plt.savefig()` just earlier in the code.

Comment: May I know why the need to save and re-upload it back? I assume you want to bypass something in order to do something on the step. Maybe a little explanation can help me to suggest a better alternative rather than save-reupload approach here

Comment: I also thought that `plt.show()` erases the image. But it is not the case. Moving it after `plt.savefig() ` does not help.

Comment: I save it to the file to convert it to bitmap later with: `img.tobitmap()`

Comment: Why do you think that `plt.show()` doesn't erase the image?  Why do you think calling `plt.savefig()` before `plt.show()` wouldn't help? Did you test this rigorously? Did you erase the old file? Did you try with a new file name?

Comment: I have tested this.  `plt.scatter(x,y)` erases the image before `plt.show()`